# AWS Lambda arm64 not supporting SQLAlchemy for Python-3.12

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy

In my case below are the Lambda Runtime configurations.

Runtime      - Python3.12
Architecture - arm64

I have attached 2 layers to my lambda function. Each layer has a set of packages as below.

| layer1 | layer2 |
| --- | --- |
| SQLAlchemy==2.0.21 | country-converter |
| aws-xray-sdk | urllib3 |
| boto3 | psycopg2-binary |
| botocore | psycopg2 |
| aws-lambda-context==1.1.0 |  |
| requests |  |
| cryptography |  |

My function of the lambda is whenever it receives a request it call a RDS (postgres DB) to fetch the data, process it and put in queue. I am using SQLALchemy to establish the connection with DB. It seems I am facing an issue while running create_engine method and I am not sure what is the reason for that. In my cloudwatch I could see the below error always.

**Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'sample.main': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg**

**NOTE:**
All the above lambda, layer and queue creation are made through terraform
So, previously I am using Python3.8 and Architecture as X86_64 processor. So, now as a part of recent changes in code I also made changes in Lambda Runtime configurations to Python3.12 and arm64.

I have tried for different versions of the package as well as tried for Python3.11 version I am ending up getting the same error.

Comment: Why do you need ARM?

Comment: As a part of Cost reduction, and makes code to execute faster we have decided to move to ARM.

NOTE: For the same lambda I have used ARM processor with Python-3.8 version, and it could be effectively seen that the time taken for execution was considerably reduced (Tried for more than 10k executions). So, we have decided to move to ARM along with Python version upgrade.